# Community Bot and Identify Questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, identify

Simply put, is there a way to tell the Community Bot to ignore questions that are marked as `identify` questions?

When [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/27862/movie-about-a-blonde-woman-strip-searched-in-office-by-a-redhead) got bumped, it reminded me that I'd been wondering if this was possible.

If so, is this something people would appreciate?

It seems that, particularly among certain users, `identify` questions get a lot of dislike... I don't care strongly either way, honestly, I like the challenge (assuming there's enough info to go off of)... but I do get why people dislike them.

That being said, I don't know that the identify questions without an accepted answer **deserve** to be dredged out of the past by the Community Bot... and, honestly, I feel like most of the questions it brings back are identify questions.

Is there an alternate method if it's not possible? eg: more strict closing of abandoned identify questions or identify questions without sufficient info?

Comment: Well, that's like treating the symptoms instead of the disease. I'd love if *Community* would keep its hands of this shit, but the sad truth is that those questions are valid first class citizens of this site and thus seem to have all the right to get bumped by *Community*. If many of the unanswered old questions are identification questions that should tell us something else than that we should just try to shut up the *Community* user.

Comment: Then, does the policy need to change? http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/380/should-we-close-older-identify-questions We can't force askers to come back and accept answers to questions... and the only thing keeping the questions around, based on the policy, is that someone has attempted to answer them.

Comment: At least it should be extended from "unanswered" to "without an upvoted or accepted answer". But this wouldn't really change *Community*'s bumping behaviour much. Afterall an unanswered or unaccepted question is absolutely no problem in general, just that ID-askers have an affinity to not even considering the review of any possible answers. But that isn't really the *Community* user's problem.

Comment: And afterall, if Community doesn't dig out those old unanswered things from the past, the chances for them to ever get an answer are even lower. And an answered ID question is still better than an unanswered one (even if not as good as a closed one ;-)).

Comment: Related: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1547/49.